# On using std::vector<class type Foo> as raw array Foo []

Tags: c++, stl

I know that vectors are guaranteed to have the same underlying memory layout as arrays. So for POD (plain-old-data) type like `int`, `vector<int> a` can be used as `SomeCFun(&a[0], a.size())` when `a` is non-empty. I'd like to know that when the element type is (complex) Class type, does the trick still work safely?

Comment: The type has no influence on the layout of the array or how a C-style array (or the vector) behaves.

Comment: Note that the title is a bit off. You cannot use the contents of a `vector<T>` as an array of `T`. What you can do is obtain a pointer to `T`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it'll work.  An alternative is `SomeCFun(a.data(), a.size())` - but whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is guaranteed to be true for *any* type `T`.